# How to use aggregation function in join condition using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have two data frames and I am trying to join both the data frames on the id  and date column.

The join condition is like this:

```
df1.join(df2, 
    (df1.id == df2.id) & 
     F.when(df1.date < df2.agg(F.min(df2.start_date)),True)
     .when(df1.date.between(df2.start_date, edf2.end_date), True)
     .otherwise(None)
     how='left'
)
```

When I am trying to do this it is throwing an Attribute error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

**What I want?**

```
Sample data:

df1:     id     date          name
          1     20190821      Ney
          1     20190828      Ron
          1     20190823      Mes
          1     20190819      Rod
          1     20190701      Sun

df2(lookup): 
         id     start_date    end_date   group_id
          1     20190827      20301212          C
          1     20190823      20190826          C
          1     20190821      20190822          B

Expected output:

         id     date          name       group_id 
          1     20190821      Ney               B
          1     20190828      Ron               C
          1     20190823      Mes               C
          1     20190819      Rod               B
          1     20190701      Sun               B
```

If df1.date less then min df2.start_date then it should pick group_id of min df2.star_date i.e B

Is there any efficient way to do this(data size is huge)?

Comment: You can't use aggregate functions inside the `join` like that. You almost certainly can achieve your desired outcome with a different method, but it's hard to say without seeing a [mcve].

Comment: Hey pault, updated the question with sample records and what I want as the output.